# Consistent ApplicationData path between WinForms Apps and Windows Service contexts in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-services, environment

I use the following code to build a desired path for an XML file:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

When executed from a Windows Forms application, it returns:

```
C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Roaming\...\Database.xml
```

When executed from within a Windows Service, it returns:

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\...\Database.xml
```

I am now resorting to having a custom installer action persist the path in a registry key since the custom action will have a desktop context. If there is a better approach, please let me know.

What I am really interested in finding out is why the behavior is different in the first place. The Windows Service in question is set up to use the `LocalSystem` account in case that matters.

Comment: ApplicationData is user specific... you sure you don't want CommonApplicationData?

Comment: "The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user." - why would you expect it to be the same for different users?

Comment: Either one of you should post this as an answer. I have not tested it out as yet but it makes complete sense since the desktop app is running under the logged in user while the service is running under LocalSystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only you know what the specific requirements are for this folder, but if it's to share data between multiple users, `ApplicationData` is the wrong choice:

> The directory that serves as a common repository for application-specific data for the current roaming user.
>
> A roaming user works on more than one computer on a network. A roaming user's profile is kept on a server on the network and is loaded onto a system when the user logs on

See the [`SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enumeration and pick an appropriate value that fits your requirements - one that doesn't depend on a specific user. Most of these start with `Common`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you should check and make sure that two apps are running by the same user.
I tested your code in both winform app and webservice app, but their values are the same, so I can't find your real problem.
good luck!